how to achive this ( like i need to get orgonization code in app.module.ts ) instead of using the includes of , i want like how to get the param-snap
if am calling a method from app.module.ts that present in another service class it's work, at the same time if am import route in that service it will get circular dependencies . however i need to get the orgcode by using => ( const orgcode = this.route.snapshot.firstChild?.paramMap.get('orgcode') || 'SR';
)
but if am try to do that then i'll get the circular dependencies , how to acive this ??[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/MBOYOqSp.png)
am trying to get some code from the url by using the snapshot to get . in an service class .
but am calling that service from the app.module.ts. if am try to call any service classes that import router then i'll get the circular dependencies problem
